# How to use Projections with references?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a mapping that has two references to two other mappings.

Firstly, would I create sub-criteria or create aliases?

So I have:

`Base.Property1
Base.Property2
Base.Reference1.Property1
Base.Reference1.Property2
Base.Reference2.Property1
Base.Reference2.Property2`

I want to project my query to just these 6 properties.

I have managed to use Projections on a query on just one table, but I'm having difficulty when it comes to multiple tables.

would I do something like (for each reference):
`criteria.CreateCrtieria(bla)
         .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
         .Add(/*Add projections*/))
         .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean(type));`

Or just create aliases and have projections on the original criteria like so:

`criteria.CreateAlias("reference1", "r1").CreateAlias("reference2", "r2")
         .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
         .Add(Projections.Property("baseProperty1")
         .Add(Projections.Property("r1.property1")
         .Add(Projections.Property("r2.property2")) /*etc*/
         .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean(baseType));`

I don't know if the previous two ideas actually work - they don't seem to, but I don't know if that's because I've forgotten something or if they're along totally the wrong lines.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution ended up requiring me to write a new Transformer. I'm not going to paste the code because it's fairly long and at the moment quite hacky. But for anyone interested:

Rather than doing `.Add(Projections.Property("r1.property1")`

I did `.Add(Projections.Property("r1.property1"), "SubType.Property1")`

Then in the transformer the alias "SubType.Property1" has a tuple value associated with it. I split the alias up and construct a SubType, and for any aliases associated with it, do the same as what the existing transformer does (assign values to those properties on that type), and then finally set the subtype object as a value to the property on the base type.

It's probably completely against the concept of Projections but it works, and works quite well, considering it was hacked together in a couple of hours.

Comment: So your partially building your base type based on the columns the user selects? Do the other properties on your base class just get defaults?

Answer (score 1):

Using the CreateAlias methods on the Criteria API allow you to join across to your referenced objects and allow you to project out the properties.

You assign each referenced type an **alias** which you then use to access the properties of the referenced objects.

Also please be aware that you need to make sure the names of the properties in the object you are projecting into are an exact match in the projection list.

You can also specify the JoinType on the CreateAlias methods as well should you want to force a InnerJoin instead of a LeftJoin.

```
var query = session.CreateCriteria<Base>()
             .CreateAlias("Base.Reference1","ref1")
             .CreateAlias("Base.Reference2","ref2")
             .SetProjection(
               Projections.ProjectionList()
               .Add(Projections.Property("Base.BaseProperty"),"DtoBaseProperty")
               .Add(Projections.Property("ref1.property1"),"DtoProperty1")
               .Add(Projections.Property("ref2.property2"),"DtoProperty2")
             )
             .SetResultTransFormer(Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(ProjectionDto)))
             .List<ProjectionDto>();

public class ProjectionDto{
    public string DtoBaseProperty;
    public string DtoProperty1;
    public string DtoProperty2;
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to project onto the original type? I have 100 columns in that base table and the user can choose to view ANY combination of those 100.

Comment: You can but I don't think it's going to help you much with your dynamic display requirement.

Comment: How? Surely the other values in the base entity can be default values and the properties I do need are the projected values?

Comment: Yes but then on your display page you are still going to have to know which properties from your object you want to display. So your going to end up with a list<displayproperty> loop or a whole lot of if statements to produce your columns. What we need is to take the results from the projection and create a typed datarow from the metadata then you have something you can easily loop over.

Comment: I have already set it up so it loops over selected properties. If I'm going the strongly typed DTO route surely I'd need 100! DTOs, no?

Comment: If I do that the base properties get projected but not the referenced objects properties. Any ideas?

Comment: I thought that might happen. =(. You can always just return .List() in the query which will return a list of objects then try stuffing those into a datatable. You can build the datatable from the list of properties that the user has selected.

Comment: You may also need to remove the ResultTransformer call as well.

Comment: @Harry, a projection is a flattened representation of your data, it can not map properly onto a hierarchical structure like a domain entity. Think of it as a row returned by a SQL query.